# Filemode Append in WebClient FileDownloadAsync

Tags: c#, webclient

So I'm on the process of understanding the Webclient and creating a download manager during the process. I would like to add pause, resume to my download manager.

So far I've managed to override the GetWebRequest method of the WebClient class in order to add a range when resuming a download.

```
 class CustomWebClient : WebClient
{
    private readonly long bytesDownloaded;

    public CustomWebClient(long bytesDownloaded)
    {
        this.bytesDownloaded= bytesDownloaded;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.AddRange(this.bytesDownloaded);
        return request;
    }
}
```

But since the DownloadFileAsync method overwrites any existing file with the same name I cannot resume the download.
If I could override the DownloadFileAsync to set the FileMode to append I could get this problem sorted. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: have it download the partial content to a temp area and then append it to the other portion of the file?

Comment: That's what I've been thinking about. I'll give it a shot.